# In Sqlite, can I begin a transaction with a SAVEPOINT?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In Sqlite, can I begin a transaction with a SAVEPOINT?

For example:

```
SAVEPOINT A
....
BEGIN TRANSACTION
....
COMMIT TRANSACTION
....
RELEASE SAVEPOINT A
```

Answer (score 0):

See [official documentation for SAVEPOINT](https://sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html).

Technically the answer is **yes** to the title question, but the **code is not valid** because you cannot begin another transaction after invoking the first SAVEPOINT. If you want the equivalent of a "nested transaction", you need to invoke another SAVEPOINT. There are other important points to consider, but it's not appropriate to reproduce the entire document here. Sometimes it is worth searching for and going to the source rather than asking on Stack Overflow.